# SQLite ROUND(X,Y) doesn't work for trailing zero when using currency values

Tags: javascript, sqlite, rounding

I am displaying a currency value from my sqlite table onto my page.  I am using the ROUND(X,Y) function that sqlite provides but whenever I do something like ROUND(money,2) the 0 at the end never shows up.  I know it is doing it to two decimal places because whenever the result isn't a 0 it does show up.

For example:  I get $25.35 (this is fine) but if the value is $25.30, I get $25.3

Is there any solution to this?

My code to display the values:

```
transaction.executeSql('SELECT ROUND(money,2) FROM table1', [],
                                      function(transaction, result) {
                                      if (result != null && result.rows != null) {
                                      for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                                      var row = result.rows.item(i);
                                      $('#placeonpage').append('$'+row['ROUND(money,2)']);
                                      }
                                      }
                                      },errorHandler);
               },errorHandler,nullHandler);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ROUND function does not return a string, it returns a number.
When JavaScript then converts the number into a string, it uses only as much digits as needed.

You must do the formatting in the JavaScript code:

```
.append('$' + row['money'].toFixed(2));
```

(In this case, you don't need to do any rounding in SQL.)

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been searching for an answer for ages now!